# Troubleshooting Motherboard Video Out with Ubuntu 18.04 (Gigabyte Z170X-UD3)

Tags: hdmi, motherboard

I am using a recent (fresh) install of a Ubuntu 18.04 on an i7 6700k in a Gigabyte Z170X-UD3 Motherboard and a GTX 1070 as the GPU. Using the Nvidia GPU I am able to get full functionality from both monitors. The HDMI out on my Motherboard produces no signal on whatever monitor I plug it in to. This is true across multiple cables and multiple monitors. Using HardInfo System Profiler, I notice that only the Nvidia device seems to show up under "PCI Devices" as a VGA controller, and I don't see any entries there that appear to be the integrated Graphics controller from Intel... How do I go about getting the computer to recognize and enable the HDMI out on the motheboard? Last system I had installed it worked fine, but that was Windows and the board has Windows specific drivers available on its site.